# Adding Maps to a List results in adding the same Map multiple times

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, java-io

I am trying to read a table from a *csv text file* and generate a table (`List` of `Hashmap`s) in java.

For which I'm reading each *line* of text file, constructing a `Hashmap<String, String>` record out of the *line* and appending it to a `ArrayList` at the end of each iteration.

I am expecting a single instance of each line from text file to appear only once in the List, but all getting is the last row from text file appearing `n+1` times, n being the last row number.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    FileReader filObj = null;
    try {
        filObj = new FileReader(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\testData.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(filObj);
    
    List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> myTable = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> myRecord = new HashMap<String, String>();
    
    String line = null;
    int ext = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //System.out.println(line);
        if (ext == 0) {
            headers = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
        } else {
            int index = 0;
            for (String each : line.split(",")) {
                myRecord.put(headers.get(index), each);
                index++;
            }
            System.out.println("myrecord:" + myRecord);
        }
        myTable.add(myRecord);
        ext++;
        System.out.println("My Table:" + myTable);
    }
}
```

the `testData.txt` file contents are as below

```
TransactionNumber,TransactionType,Amount,TransactionDate,TransactionRemarks
123456,Credit,4000,07/10/2021,Salary Credited
123333,Debit,7000,05/10/2021,Fuel
123446,Credit,3000,01/10/2021,Refund
```

and the console output is as below:

```
My Table:[{}]
myrecord:{TransactionType=Credit, TransactionNumber=123456, Amount=4000, TransactionRemarks=Salary Credited, TransactionDate=07/10/2021}
My Table:[{TransactionType=Credit, TransactionNumber=123456, Amount=4000, TransactionRemarks=Salary Credited, TransactionDate=07/10/2021}, {TransactionType=Credit, TransactionNumber=123456, Amount=4000, TransactionRemarks=Salary Credited, TransactionDate=07/10/2021}]
myrecord:{TransactionType=Debit, TransactionNumber=123333, Amount=7000, TransactionRemarks=Fuel, TransactionDate=05/10/2021}
My Table:[{TransactionType=Debit, TransactionNumber=123333, Amount=7000, TransactionRemarks=Fuel, TransactionDate=05/10/2021}, {TransactionType=Debit, TransactionNumber=123333, Amount=7000, TransactionRemarks=Fuel, TransactionDate=05/10/2021}, {TransactionType=Debit, TransactionNumber=123333, Amount=7000, TransactionRemarks=Fuel, TransactionDate=05/10/2021}]
myrecord:{TransactionType=Credit, TransactionNumber=123446, Amount=3000, TransactionRemarks=Refund, TransactionDate=01/10/2021}
My Table:[{TransactionType=Credit, TransactionNumber=123446, Amount=3000, TransactionRemarks=Refund, TransactionDate=01/10/2021}, {TransactionType=Credit, TransactionNumber=123446, Amount=3000, TransactionRemarks=Refund, TransactionDate=01/10/2021}, {TransactionType=Credit, TransactionNumber=123446, Amount=3000, TransactionRemarks=Refund, TransactionDate=01/10/2021}, {TransactionType=Credit, TransactionNumber=123446, Amount=3000, TransactionRemarks=Refund, TransactionDate=01/10/2021}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the **same** instance of the *map* to the *list* at each iteration step. And this *map* gets added to the *list* `n + 1` times because the line `myTable.add(myRecord);` gets executed after reading the headers (I guess that wasn't your intention).

Instead, you need to move the creation of the map into the `while` loop, to instantiate a *new map* for every line of text.

There are few more issues in your code:

- You're not closing the stream, always use [*try with resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make sure that resources would be properly closed.
- Don't throw from the `main()`, it's not a good practice;
- Write your code against interfaces [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)
- Since Java 7 we can use [*diamond*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond) and since Java 10 [`var`](https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference.html) to reduce verbosity of code.

Your code might be rewritten like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    List<Map<String, String>> myTable = new ArrayList<>();
    
    try (var reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\testData.txt"))) {
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        
        String line = null;
        int ext = 0;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);
            if (ext == 0) {
                headers = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
                ext++;
                continue;
            }
            
            Map<String, String> myRecord = new HashMap<>();

            int index = 0;
            for (String each : line.split(",")) {
                myRecord.put(headers.get(index), each);
                index++;
            }
            
            myTable.add(myRecord);
            ext++;

            System.out.println("myrecord:" + myRecord);
            System.out.println("My Table:" + myTable);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your structures are wrong: you add the same `HashMap` to the list `myTable` over and over.

Instead of a list of hashmaps you probably would need a map of lists:

```
Map<String, List<String>> mytable = new HashMap<>();
```

This way you can store multiple values for each header (the header is still the key of the map).

The order of values is still preserved as the order of rows.

When you read in the headers, you can also initialize the map:

```
if (ext == 0){
    headers = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
    for (String header : headers) {
    myList.put(header, new List<String>());
}
```

To add a value you then have to fetch the list according to the header and add a value to its end:

```
else {
    String[] values = line.split(",");
    for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
        myTable.get(headers.get(index)).add(values[index]);
    }
}
```